# Why does MS Graph calendar event deletion respond with Transfer-Encoding header, violating the HTTP spec?

Tags: http, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, transfer-encoding, http-status-code-204

My application has been in production for several months and everything worked fine. Howwever,
since February 24, 2023, whenever it deletes a calendar event via `DELETE /me/calendars/{id}/events/{id}`, the response from Microsoft Graph includes a `Transfer-Encoding` header despite this being a `204` status:

```http
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
request-id: *redacted*
client-request-id: *redacted*
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: *redacted*
Preference-Applied: IdType=ImmutableId
Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2023 10:16:44 GMT
```

As far as I understand section [6.1 "Transfer-Encoding"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9112#section-6.1-10) of RFC 9112, that header is illegal in this situation:

> A server MUST NOT send a Transfer-Encoding header field in any response with a status code of 1xx (Informational) or 204 (No Content).

Note that the event is deleted successfully. However, due to the HTTP spec violation, the `java.net.http` HTTP client throws an `IOException` saying "unexpected content length header with 204 response". (Reading the source, one can see that despite the wording of that message, it is also used when a `Transfer-Encoding` header is set.)

I changed my code to catch and ignore this specific exception, but this is a bad workaround as the exception being thrown still slows down the application.

So far, my production server logged 1644 occurrences of this problem; the latest one was this morning. I therefore guess these are the majority of or even all deletion requests my application issued to MS Graph.

<sup>Note: I already [posted this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1205295/why-does-event-deletion-respond-with-transfer-enco) on the Microsoft Q&A forums, but got no answers.</sup>

#### Questions

- Is there anything I am overlooking?
- Can anybody else confirm the presence of the `Transfer-Encoding` header?
- Was this an intentional change that was announced somewhere?

Comment: I logged a case with Microsoft about this back in March https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1184068/has-the-email-delete-message-endpoint-started-to-r and they accepted it as a bug. If you can log your own support case as this helps push the PM's to fix it faster.

Comment: Oooh, great, thanks a lot! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it gladly.